# set ACL by NFS V4 IBM

Tags: linux, directory, nfs, acl, access-control

I have the following directories and files:

```
/project/
  src/
    test.txt
    temp.xls
  data/
     data.xls
```

The owner is always `mytu` and the Group is `mytug`. Now there is a user (e.g. user1) woh is member of `mytug`. He should have access for directory `data/` but not for `src/`.

How can I handle this with ACL by NFS V4 IBM?

Here is my current not working result:

```
#NFSv4 ACL
#owner:mytu
#group:mytug
special:owner@:rwxc:allow
(X)READ/LIST (X)WRITE/CREATE (X)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
(-)DELETE    (X)DELETE_CHILD (X)CHOWN        (X)EXEC/SEARCH (X)WRITE_ACL (X)WRITE_ATTR (X)WRITE_NAMED

special:group@:rwx-:allow
(X)READ/LIST (X)WRITE/CREATE (X)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
(-)DELETE    (X)DELETE_CHILD (-)CHOWN        (X)EXEC/SEARCH (-)WRITE_ACL (-)WRITE_ATTR (-)WRITE_NAMED

special:everyone@:----:allow
(-)READ/LIST (-)WRITE/CREATE (-)APPEND/MKDIR (X)SYNCHRONIZE (X)READ_ACL  (X)READ_ATTR  (X)READ_NAMED
(-)DELETE    (-)DELETE_CHILD (-)CHOWN        (-)EXEC/SEARCH (-)WRITE_ACL (-)WRITE_ATTR (-)WRITE_NAMED

user:user1:rw--:deny:DirInherit:InheritOnly
(X)READ/LIST (X)WRITE/CREATE (-)APPEND/MKDIR (-)SYNCHRONIZE (-)READ_ACL  (-)READ_ATTR  (-)READ_NAMED
(-)DELETE    (-)DELETE_CHILD (-)CHOWN        (-)EXEC/SEARCH (-)WRITE_ACL (-)WRITE_ATTR (-)WRITE_NAMED
```

The problem is that user1 has still access to directory src. What is wrong the the ACL?

Comment: ACL are set on dir and auto propagate, which ACL are you showing ? those for src or for data ?

Comment: Those for src are shown.

Comment: why not simply remove user1 from acl on src ?

Comment: User1 is in group mytug. This is definitely necessary. He should have access to data, but not to src. So I want to deny the access for src.

Comment: then set **user:user1:----:allow** ?

Comment: This did not work. He had still access. Maybe due to the fact that he is in mytug that has access to src folder.